# Image expression URL in Jasper Reports

Tags: jasper-reports

I would like to embed an image into my JasperReports jrxml file. I have this directory structure.

```
Tomcat Root
 webapps
  reports
   -->images
    --> company_logo.jpg
   -->reports
    -->sample.jasper
   -->WEB-INF
    -->classes
```

And I tried doing this thinking that this is relative to my reports context root

```xml
<image>
 <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="104" height="40"/>
 <imageExpression class="java.lang.String">
  <![CDATA["images/company_logo.jpg"]]>
 </imageExpression>
</image>
```

..and this also

```xml
<image>
 <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="104" height="40"/>
 <imageExpression class="java.lang.String">
  <![CDATA["/images/company_logo.jpg"]]>
 </imageExpression>
</image>
```

but it always says there was an error loading bytes from location `JRLoader`.

I tried doing this and it works, but I am a bit confused why my first two attempt doesn't.

Is this really how you embed images in JasperReports? Do you need to supply the whole path?  I am thinking that there should be a page relative
something.

```xml
<image>
 <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="104" height="40"/>
 <imageExpression class="java.lang.String">
  <![CDATA["http://localhost:8080/reports/images/company_logo.jpg"]]>
 </imageExpression>
</image>
```

I am a bit puzzled about the correct way.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`<![CDATA["../images/company_logo.jpg"]]>` should do the trick. The path is relative to your .jasper file.

Comment: A point to be noted is that the file-names and paths are case-sensitive!

Comment: This did not work for me when Spring was compiling the Jasper report files on the fly. I had to resort to the technique described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376725/using-ireport-with-a-relative-path)

Answer (score 14):

You need to create a PARAMETER of type String called for example **CONTEXT**, and from your JSP send the servlet context:

```
parameters.put("CONTEXT",this.getServletContext().getRealPath("/"));
```

Now, in your report you use the parameter:

```
$P{CONTEXT}.toString()+"reports/images/logo.png"
```

The same apply for sub reports or other web resources, example:

```
$P{CONTEXT}.toString()+"reports/OrdenCompraAlmacen_Items.jasper"
```

I hope it is useful.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: it worked to me!!! thanks!!   even if i load the path from database: hmParams.put("CONTEXT",pathReceta.getValor());                                                              then I need to add a extra "/" like this: $P{CONTEXT}.toString()+"/reports/images/logo.png"

Answer (score 9):

With **.jrxml** when use an absolute path with image, when the packaged **jar** filr will be deployed you will get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name
at sun.misc.URLClassPath$Loader.findResource(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.misc.URLClassPath.findResource(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
```

Try to load resource as:

```
<imageExpression><![CDATA[this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/img/mdg_logo.jpg")]]></imageExpression>
```

Comment: for master the above expression is fine, how about sub-report

Answer (score 3):

sometimes is better use File.separtor: `"ima" + File.separator + "logo.jpg"`

Answer (score 0):

Use the below expression in the image Expression of jasper report IDE on image properties of the jrxml and the relative image path

Accordingly change w.r.t path

```
getClass().getResource("META-INF/resources/webjars/Bank/themes/default/images/Logo.png").openStream()
```

Answer (score 0):

This way the path is relative to your current working directory of your project. "." means current working directory.

Answer (score -1):

Put your picture in the following structure:

```
webapps
  reports
      -->reports
          -->sample.jasper
 -->WEB-INF
      -->classes
          -->images
              --> company_logo.jpg

<imageExpression class="java.lang.String">
    <![CDATA["company_logo.jpg"]]>
</imageExpression>
```

Comment: English please. [so] is an English-only website. You can go to [a51] to see if there's a site or proposal for one in your language.